# Prevent triggering windows resize event when css property is changed using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have added a windows resize event on my page
it is called whenever page size is changed.

but when I update css values for a div element inside page using jquery css and animate it automatically triggers windows resize event.

this happens only for IE

I want to prevent resize event from executing on manual change of size by animate or css methods

Here is my code

for window resize

```
window.onresize=function(){ ... };
```

for div size change

```
$('div#divtest').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'z-index': '1', 'background-color': '#f6f6f6' }).animate({
                    width: '20%', 
                    height : $('div#divother').height() - 29
                }, 0);
```

**EDIT:**
i do not want to make any change in resize event reason is it is page wise different so i have to make change in all existing events

any chance i can temporary turn it off

Comment: You mean `I want to prevent resize event from executing on scripted change of size by animate or css methods`

Comment: yes, OR can i do something that will effect in every resize event with out making change in all resize events (like adding some generalized code in script which will executed before resize event called from any page so i can apply code suggested by vijayP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved this.
thanks to vijayP for flag suggestion.
but instead of puting flag in each resize function i just override window.onresize function

i add following code in master page script /general script

```
(function($) {
        var oldresize = window.onresize;

        window.onresize = function() {
            if (CallPageResize)
                return oldresize.call(this);
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

where CallPageResize is flag and its value is set as follow

```
CallPageResize = false; $('div#divtest').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'z-index': '1', 'background-color': '#f6f6f6' }).animate({
            width: '20%',
            height: $('div#divother').height() - 29
        }, 0);
        CallPageResize = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by following way:

Before applying `css` animation set some flag like following:

```
$('div#divtest').data("css_animation", true); //set the flag

$('div#divtest').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'z-index': '1', 'background-color': '#f6f6f6' }).animate({
    width: '20%', 
    height : $('div#divother').height() - 29
}, 0,function() {
    // Animation complete.
    $('div#divtest').data("css_animation", false); //reset the flag
});
```

And in `resize` we can check whether flag is set or not as follows:

```
window.onresize=function(){ 

    var flagValue = $('div#divtest').data("css_animation"); //fetch the flag value
    //don't do anything if resize is getting called via css animation
    if(flagValue === true)
        return;
    ... 

};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i do not want to make any change in resize event reason is it is page wise different so i have to make change in all existing events any chance i can temporary turn off resize event and than turn it on OR any other option do you have. sorry i forgot to add this detail in my question

Answer (score 0):

To avoid unnecessary window resize event, compare the previous window width and height and proceed the window resize event if width or height differs. This is only a workaround solution.

```
private previousWindowWidth = 0; private previousWindowHeight = 0;

private onWindowResize(): void {

var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var windowHt = window.innerHeight;
if (previousWindowWidth  === windowWidth && previousWindowHeight === 
    windowHt ) {
    return;
 }

previousWindowWidth = windowWidth ;
previousWindowHeight = windowHt ;

// continue with other operations
..................................
}
```